# Sinhala fonts in Andriod 5.0 (lollipop)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have upgraded my Samsung S5 to lollipop recently. Now I am unable to see any Sinhala fonts. Any fix for this ?

Thanks !